# JQuery 3.5.0 ajax hungs browser for empty response

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser

We is in process to migrate a product from jquery 1.11.1 to 3.5.0.
All works pretty well expecto one ajax request which responses zero length response body.
Below is sample for two requests:

```
 $.ajax({
            headers : headers, //{}
            cache : RESTParams.cache, //false
            type : type,//'POST'
            url : RESTParams.url,//Doesn't hang: 1) 'api/locale', hangs: 2) 'api/environment/save'
            data : RESTParams.isSimpleData ? RESTParams.data : JSON.stringify(RESTParams.data), //1)'{"newLocale":"de_DE"}' 2)
            dataType: RESTParams.dataType,//1) 'json' 2) tried 'json', undefined but hangs for both
            contentType : RESTParams.contentType, //'application/json'
            async : RESTParams.async,//true
            success : function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
    })
```

Ajax with request which returns a json as response body results with success function call.
Response headers for it:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 26 Dec 2021 10:06:48 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
```

Response body:

```
{errors: Array(0)}
```

But Ajax with request which returns none as response body doesn't call functions success nor error. Browser hangs and we have one choice to close of it only in process mananager
Response headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 26 Dec 2021 10:14:50 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
```

Response body is empty

Could some one to explain what is wrong? Could some one to advise how to solve the problem?

Comment: Why not 3.6.0? Latest

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.